# JTable not visible when added to Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel

I have JButton in the front panel. When it is clicked it should display the data in table format. I have assigned the data and column names to JTable parameter but it is not visible in the front end. I confirmed the values are assigned correctly but not sure why table is not visible in the panel. Here is my code:

```
private void disPlayDataActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
       sql = "select * from persons";   

    try {
              Statement  st = con.createStatement();
              ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
              ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
              int columnCount=metaData.getColumnCount();
              String[]columnNames=new String[columnCount];

              for(int i=0;i< columnNames.length;i++){
                columnNames[i]=metaData.getColumnName(i+1);

        }                       
        ArrayList<String[]> rows=new ArrayList<>();
        while(rs.next()){
            String[]currentrow=new String[columnCount];
            for(int i=0;i<columnCount;i++){
                currentrow[i]=rs.getString(i+1);

        }

              rows.add(currentrow);
        }   
        String[][] rowsArray=new String[rows.size()][columnCount];
        rowsArray=rows.toArray(rowsArray);
        JTable jt=new JTable(rowsArray,columnNames);
        jPanel2.add(jt);
        jt.setVisible(true);



    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EmployeePanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    finally{

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the `Layout` for `jpanel2`?

Comment: In any case, I recommend you read the following [article on Using Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

Comment: @TT, addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE), I haven't define the panel layout manually. I was using the Netbeans GUI designer to place the panel inside the main frame.

Comment: @James kindly if you are satiesfied with my answer then accept and upvote to my ans. Thank you.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this one,

```
JTable jt=new JTable(rowsArray,columnNames);  
jt.setBounds(30,40,200,300);   // you can put dimension as per your wish...

JScrollPane sp=new JScrollPane(jt);  
jPanel2.add(sp);
// code fore set visible true to jpanel2...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have tried above but still not visible in Panel. are there any settings to configured for JTable ?

Comment: This looks like you are using a null layout, which is not recommended. In any case, the dimensions should then be set on the scrollpane rather than the table.

Comment: looks like other issue, for JTable only above i have given settings are enough. can you review code's other part correctly. some bit mistake there in terms of manage panel.

Comment: @TT. absolutely agree with you, but without whole code boundary i just suggest to do which i feel to better.

Comment: @TT,@Vishal gajera,Thanks mates,It works now after i have defined the panel and JScrollpanel layout properly.

Comment: Since the `JScrollPane` takes responsibility for laying out it's content, calling `setBounds` is completely pointless

Answer (score 0):

Swing's layout API is lazy, it's designed this way.  You need to tell it when you're ready for it revalidate the container hirarcy.

```
JTable jt=new JTable(rowsArray,columnNames);
jPanel2.add(jt);
jPanel2.revalidate();
jPanel2.repaint();
```

Without knowing your full code, generally speaking, it's much easier to simply have a main `JTable` and change it's model when ever you need to.